# Is there a performance difference between postbackurl and response.redirect?

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect, postbackurl

i've just created a page that needs to update that contains multiple documents. Each document can be selected from a menu on the page.

I would normally wrap this up in a multiview + update panel, however I needed to update the url as well to reflect the document selected.

At the moment I've done this using a different postbackurl (so no update panel), however this means displaying a nasty "Firefox needs to resend...2 message when the back button is clicked.

I could, instead redirect from the button event. This would have the same effect, but without the message.

The question I have is does the postbackurl method offer any significant advantages over the redirect. By advantages I mean performance.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us consider the two cases :

- no postbackurl, with redirect : the client submit the form, the server issues a redirect, the client issues a get request to the final url and gets the content
- postbackurl : the client submits the form to the postbackurl and gets the content

  Second case is better in terms of performance ( no network roundtrip to get and follow the redirect )

But redirect has some advantages in the fact that a get request is issued. (no reload or repost problem)

Anyway, I was wondering why you couldn't just use `HyperLink` with `NavigateUrl` to get to your content.

Comment: Thanks. In answer to your question, I used a button because originally, I was looking at using a redirect. You are correct in that a hyperlink would do the job given the current requirement.

Answer (score 2):

`Response.Redirect` is a simple `HTTP 302`, so performance-wise it may be 'faster' and 'lighter'.

`PostBackURL` updates the form's Action, keeping `ViewState` along with other `Page` objects. So technically slower performance with more bulk because of the increased latency.

If you want to avoid the re-POST then easiest to use Response.Redirect.

Comment: Thanks for that. I had it in my mind that it would be the reverse.